PHP permissions to do file_exists & include from different domain directories in same server?
I have 2 domains: domainA.com & domainb.com hosted on same server, same user; with paths: /var/hostdata/username/public_html/domain_a/ & /var/hostdata/username/public_html/domain_b/
Now in domainB, I tried using file_exists, file_get_contents, include on a PHP file & a XML file on domainA but all failed without any error or warning.
I tried enable php_admin_value open_basedir none in vhost file for both 2 sites but still failed.
Here's my code in /var/hostdata/username/public_html/domain_b/file.php, paths are correct, all files are available:
echo file_exists('/var/hostdata/username/public_html/domain_a/include.php') ? '1111' : '0000';
echo file_exists('/var/hostdata/username/public_html/domain_a/sitemap.xml') ? '1111' : '0000';
include('/var/hostdata/username/public_html/domain_a/include.php');

All failed. Please help me, thank you.

You need to look into the logfiles. If a file can not be included, it will be logged.

just checked, there's no any log in both error.log or access.log?

"but all failed without any error or warning" - and just to, you have error reporting set to maximum noise?

error.log is the one. The access.log is for requests the webserver passes to php.

Just from a general app design perspective, 1. If you need to rely on common code, that common code should be in a common location. Don't be touching files from other applications. 2. Applications should be isolated from each other in such a way as they are forbidden from touching anything other than their own files. This protects you from both accidentally breaking one app with the other, as well as containing any security breaches within the compromised app itself.

Yeah, php_admin_value open_basedir none works perfectly, I forgot to apply this setting to SSL section in vhost, just in normal vhost (no SSL) so it did not work
